# MySQL nested query based on the last 10 dates

Tags: mysql, database, select

I have a database that stores the temperature reading of each sensor in a along with the sensor ID, and date the reading was taken.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `date` FROM `temperatureData` ORDER BY `date` ASC LIMIT 10
```

this allows me to select the last 10 readings that are going to be plotted in a chart.
there are up to 40 sensor readings for each date.

I tried doing the following.

```
SELECT `date`, `sensor`, `temp` 
FROM `temperatureData` 
WHERE `date` = (
    SELECT DISTINCT `date` FROM `temperatureData` ORDER BY `date` ASC LIMIT 10
)
```

Can anyone assist me as to how to select all the readings for the dates that are returned back from the last 10 dates?

Thanks in advance.
Boris

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

You just need `in` instead of `=`:

```
SELECT `date`, `sensor`, `temp` 
FROM `temperatureData` 
WHERE `date` IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT `date` FROM `temperatureData` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 10
)
```

NB: if you want the readings of the *last* 10 dates, you probably want to `ORDER BY date DESC` instead of `ASC`. I changed that too.

In MySQL 8.0, this could also be rewritten with window function `dense_rank()`:

```
SELECT `date`, `sensor`, `temp` 
FROM (
    SELECT
        `date`, 
        `sensor`, 
        `temp` 
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY `date` DESC) rn
    FROM `temperatureData`
) t
WHERE rn <= 10
```

---

**Edit**

To workaround the limitation of MySQL 5.7 not supporting `LIMIT` in subqueries with `IN`, you can use a join instead:

```
SELECT t.`date`, t.`sensor`, t.`temp` 
FROM `temperatureData` t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT `date` FROM `temperatureData` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 10
) d ON d.`date` = t.`date`
```

Comment: Thanks for that @GMB i am running 5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

Looks like I may need to upgrade as im getting an error.
#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: @AndrewHooper: I see... I edited my answer with a solution for this.

Comment: This works a treat and again thank you. 
Just an FYI the project is a temperature array being installed in Mt Erebus down in Antarctica. there are up to 40 sensors and the data comes back via the Iridium sat network and is added to the database.
Its been a fun little project :)
Looking forward to seeing the data coming from it when it gets installed on Sunday.